# Why is javascript audio.pause() function not working?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, vue.js, html5-audio

I'm making a simple music app, and I want the user to be able to toggle pause/play of a song by clicking on the song. However, whenever I click on the song the first time, it plays like usual, but then it doesn't pause when I click it again, and the audio.paused variable doesn't toggle either. Any idea why? here's the code:

```
  <div class="error" v-if="error">{{ error }}</div>
  <div v-if="playlist" class="playlist-details">

    <!-- playlist information -->
    <div class="playlist-info">
      <div class="cover">
        <img :src="playlist.coverUrl">
      </div>
      <h2>{{ playlist.title }}</h2>
      <p class="username">Created by {{ playlist.userName }}</p>
      <p class="description">{{ playlist.description }}</p>
      <button v-if="ownership" @click="handleDelete">
        Delete Playlist</button>
    </div>

    <!-- song list -->
    <div class="song-list">
      <div v-if="!playlist.songs.length">No songs have been added to this playlist yet</div>
      <div class="single-song" v-for="song in playlist.songs" :key="song.id" @click="playSong(song.id)">
        <div class="details">
          <h3>{{song.title}}</h3>
          <p>{{song.artist}}</p>
        </div>
        <button v-if="ownership" @click="handleClick(song.id)">Delete</button>
      </div>
      <AddSong v-if="ownership" :playlist="playlist"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AddSong from '@/components/AddSong.vue'
import getDocument from '@/composables/getDocument'
import getUser from '@/composables/getUser'
import { computed, ref } from 'vue'
import useDocument from '@/composables/useDocument'
import useStorage from '@/composables/useStorage'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
export default {
  props: ['id'],
  setup(props) {
    const { error, document: playlist } = getDocument('playlists', props.id)
    const { user } = getUser()
    const { deleteDoc, updateSongs } = useDocument('playlists', props.id)
    const { deleteImage } = useStorage()
    const router = useRouter()
    const ownership = computed(() => {
      return playlist.value 
        && user.value 
        && user.value.uid == playlist.value.userId
    })
    const handleDelete = async () => {
      await deleteSongs()
      await deleteImage(playlist.value.filePath)
      await deleteDoc()
      router.push({ name: 'Home'})
    }
    const handleClick = async (id) => {
      const songs = playlist.value.songs.filter((song) => {
        song.id != id
      })
      playlist.value.songs.forEach((song) => {
        if(id === song.id){
          deleteImage(song.filePath)
        }
      }) 
      await updateSongs({songs})
    }
    const playSong = async (id) => {
      
      playlist.value.songs.forEach((song) => {
        if(id === song.id){
          try{
            var audio = new Audio(song.fileUrl)
            if(audio.paused){
              audio.play();
              console.log(audio.paused)
            } else if (!audio.paused){
              audio.pause();
              console.log(audio.paused)
            }
          } catch(err){
            console.log(err.message)
          }
        }
      })
    }
    const deleteSongs = async () => {
      playlist.value.songs.forEach((song) => {
        deleteImage(song.filePath)
      })
    }
    return { error, playlist, ownership, handleDelete, handleClick, playSong, deleteSongs}
  },
  components: {AddSong}
}
```

Comment: Isn't that always a new audio object? Maybe try keeping the reference to the original

Comment: @Barry thanks! unfortunately, when I try to make the audio element a property of the song, it says that I cannot do that because I can't make html5 audio a property. Anyway around that to make it a reference to the original?

Comment: Look here: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-play-and-stop-my-audios/33419/2  in the replies someone refered to this as a solution:https://codepen.io/getreworked/pen/QrgEOG?editors=1010